# When to use web api instead of dependency injection in a Service Oriented Architecture

Tags: java, api, dependency-injection, soa, asp.net-web-api

In a project I have different processors for each request message that each of these processors can be enabled or disabled based on the configuration. I have two options, one is to use the jar library of each of these processors in my applications and use its classes and the other option is to make each of the processors like a standalone web api that get and return json objects and in this way the communication between these processors would be based on web api instead of using jar libraries. 
Which of these options do you think is better and what I need to consider when making such a decision.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what the service is, but overall...

- Using the jar will save you network hops between your client and the new service
- Conversely, if the jar is taking up a lot of your resources, it might be more performant to have it as a separate service on a different machine
- jar file is easily manageable as a project dependency, whereas api service will likely involve a more involved release process
- if you manage the jar file, you are probably prone to tighter coupling of code since you are in control of it. having an api somewhat pushes you in direction of writing somewhat cleaner code

I think it really comes down to what your jar is doing and what makes most sense with the service you've packaged in its own jar.